# Calculating $b_1,b_2,...,b_k$ where $b_i$=$a_1a_2...a_{i-1}a_{i+1}...a_k$ in minimal number of multiplications

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, computational-algebra

Let's suppose we have a set of integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k$ in $Z_n^{*}$, and that we define $b_i$ to be the multiplication $a_1a_2...a_{i-1}a_{i+1}...a_k$. Is there a way to calculate the set $\{b_1,...,b_k\}$ in less than $C*k$ multiplications between the $a_i$s? (Where $C$ is some constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this with $2*k$ multiplications i.e with $C=2$. The algorithm is outlined below:

> Initialize
>   $temp = 1$
>
> for i=$1$ to k 
>   do 
>        $b_i$ = temp 
>         temp = temp*$a_i$ 
>   end
>
> temp = $1$ 
>   for i=k to $1$ 
>   do 
>        $b_i$ = temp 
>         temp = temp*$a_i$ 
>   end

Example , $k=4$

First Pass

> $b_1$ = 1 
>  $b_2$ = $a_1$ 
>  $b_3$=$a_1*a_2$ 
>  $b_4=a_1*a_2*a_3$

Second Pass (updating the existing values of $b_i$) {temp=$1$}

> $b_4=a_1*a_2*a_3$ {temp =$a_4$}
>  $b_3$=$a_1*a_2*a_4$ {temp=$a_4*a_3$}
>  $b_2$=$a_1*a_3*a_4$ {temp=$a_4*a_3*a_2$}
>  $b_1$=$a_2*a_3*a_4${temp=$a_4*a_3*a_2*a_1$}